# Can't Run VNCsharp sample work

Tags: c#, .net, client-server, remote-desktop, vnc

I have downloaded VNCsharp sample form [here](http://cdot.senecac.on.ca/projects/vncsharp/). I run the sample on my own machine and another instance of it on a remote machine then try to connect to remote host but it throws an exception as this:"No connection could be made, because the target machine actively refused it"

What kind of issues i probably not intended?

Comment: Have you checked if the vnc server is running properly by connection to it with a different vnc client.

Comment: @Searock I didn't understand what kind of implementation has been made for Client-server negotiation as you can see [here](http://cdot.senecac.on.ca/projects/vncsharp/download.html) the sample code only implemented request and it seems no one response to request on the other side and all things i can guess is that another instance of application will response as server - or even client /:)

Comment: @Searock thank you for your help.Now I know that the VNCsharp library just plays client role and i must install a VNC server :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and set up a real vnc server properly and test the client code on that. I guess you missed something out in the server configuration so using a prepared server with .NET client will help you diagnose the problem. Also you can try enabling network tracing from app.config to see what was going on.